# HTTP 301 moved for all nginx URL to a single HTTPS

Tags: nginx, debian, http, 301-redirect

Below is a config file that I am using with Nginx to redirect all WWW and non-WWW to the https:/domain.com URL

```
server {
    listen 80 443;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl-unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl.key;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl-unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl.key;
    listen *:443 ssl;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }
}
```

In the folder located at `/usr/share/nginx` there is `www` and `lah`. When I load `www.domain.com` in my browser, it points to `lah.domain.com`

When I load `domain.com` it changes to `https://domain.com` and gives me a

> Web Page Not Available - Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

What did I enter wrongly on my Nginx configuration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what the issue was, firstly, I removed the `443` and `ssl_certificate*` from the top block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Then  I just left hte bottom block in place.

I found that in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` I had a second config file for the `lah` subdomain and there was a symlink for `default` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` that didn't exist and was using the URL for `lah.domain.com`

So, therefore it was like this:

```
[http|https]://*.domain.com -> https://lah.domain.com
```

That was what this original config file was used to do when I was testing.

Secondly, I repaired the symlink and put the below config file `default` to the location as required and removed everything else I didn't need:

```
# sudo ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1320 Jan 30 13:25 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

I put the file below, as it is, that directory as `default`:

```
server {
    listen 80 443;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl-unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl.key;
    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl-unified.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/ca-certificate/pvt/ssl.key;
    listen *:443 ssl;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }
}
```

Now it works. Everything *[http|https]* for *[www|non-www]* will redirect to: **https://domain.com**